# Adding points for each user

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sum

I want to add the points for each of user identified by mail address, Points are added to user whenever he does a task, different points for different task and need to sum all the points each day, this is what I am trying to and one more thing I am working on zend.

```
public function sumPoint($user_email)
{



     $select =  $this->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from('tbl_points', array('sum(points)'))
            ->where('emailAddress = ?', $user_email) 
            ->order('createdOn DESC');


        $totalpoints= $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select);  
  }
```

I am not sure if it is correct please let me know.

Comment: So each user would have a number of rows in the db table, each with a value in the `points` column?  And you want the total of the `points` values for a particular user?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a view in your database to handle this ?

Something like :

```
CREATE VIEW V_USERS AS (
    SELECT a.*,
    (SELECT SUM(points) FROM tbl_points where tbl_points.emailAdress = a.emailAdress) sumPoints
    FROM your_user_table a
);
```

And then, in Zend, you set the authentification table to 'V_USERS', so you'll get the number of points always ok, and it will avoid you to do the process by yourself.